# AnyLogic: Pedestrians block each other and cause congestion

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am trying to design a model wherein some pedestrians are supposed to go from target line A to target line B and some pedestrians are supposed to go from target line B to target line A. When I run the model, the pedestrians are not able to reach the respective target lines and fight each other in the middle. Is there a way to make them go around and not fight each other and form a huge clump in the middle? (I want to do this without adding pedGoTo blocks or any other blocks)

[image: Depiction]

Comment: I don't know anything about the anylogic library, but if two lines of people walked towards each other in real life and neither yielded then your situation is a likely outcome. So you either have to remove collisions or your need to let your pedestrians move up and down to avoid bumping into others and stagger the movement so they don't all move at the same time. Otherwise give them rules like regular car/foon traffic to stay left or stay right etc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In real life as @sorifiend said, if you put 1000 people in a corridor going in opposite directions, they will get stuck without the ability to move... This is what your model is representing.

Nevertheless if you are modeling ghosts, then the pedestrian library is not the right thing for you to use, instead use the process modeling library, in which agents are not obstacles of each other

But you can also try paths like this using the follow route mode in the pedGoTo block:
[image: paths]
In that case it is more likely that the pedestrians wont obstaculize each other if going in opposite directions (unless you have millions of peds moving around)